# Why is then block after Promise with 'if' not been executed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm fairly new to asynchronous programming and trying to understand why execution never goes to the 'then' block chained after the promise that contains a 'if'. Can anyone help please ?

```
var uploadResourceToView = function (edit) {
    var promises = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < inputConfig.length; i++) {
        promises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var name = 'hey';

            new Promise(function (resolve) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    return new pTree().renamePage('Home', name);
                } else {
                    return edit.addPage(name, '3D')
                }
            })
            // subsequent then()s are never executed 
            .then(function () {
                console.log('why am I not been executed ? ');
                return edit.addObject(object)
            })
            .then(function () {
                return edit.addResource('test resource', true);
            })
            .then(resolve, reject);
        });
    }

    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you never call `resolve` or `reject` for your inner promise. The return value of the executor function you pass into a `Promise` constructor is completely ignored. To settle the promise, call the `resolve` or `reject` callbacks that `new Promise` passes to the executor.

---

In terms of actually getting that overall function working, I'm guessing that `renamePage` and `addPage` return promises. If so, use them directly, no need for `new Promise` anywhere in that function:

```
var uploadResourceToView = function (edit) {
    var promises = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < inputConfig.length; i++) {
        var name = 'hey';
        var inner = i == 0 ? new pTree().renamePage('Home', name) : edit.addPage(name, '3D');
        promises.push(inner
            .then(function () {
                console.log('why am I not been executed ? ');
                return edit.addObject(object)
            })
            .then(function () {
                return edit.addResource('test resource', true);
            })
        });
    }

    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

More: [*What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it#)